# How to std::move a boost::multi_array?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-array

It doesn't appear that `multi_array` has a move constructor - is this correct? Is there a reason for this or was it just never implemented since the class seems to have been written before move semantics were available? Is there anything to be done about this in user land?

Comment: Many boost libraries are not C++11 ready, it's true. You can assume it's outdated, if the move constructor is not deleted.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use multi_array_ref and raw storage (`unique_ptr<T[]>`) to implement a movable version with the same interface

Comment: Or try swapping it around via std::swap or the boost equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.MultiArray does not support move construction (or move assignment). The only copy constructor is the one in line 229 in `boost/multi_array.hpp`.

```
  multi_array(const multi_array& rhs);
```

(Among other reasons that's why I implemented my own multidimensional array library that supports move semantics: https://godbolt.org/z/M1bWGj8YW)